# SP2010: Add option to "New Document" in document library: "New Custom Wiki Page"

Tags: 2010, document-library, custom, wiki-pages

I have multiple document libraries containing links to Wiki Pages. I need to have an option under the "New Wiki Page" to create a "New Custom Wiki Page". When i click that new option, a new custom Wiki Page should be added to the document library. Some default (a table with headers) data should be on that new page. When a new document library is created, that option should be avaible.

[image]

can someone help me with my problem or have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: [Creating a Page layouts content types](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=638).
It describes everything you need to know. Just make sure you *select parent content type from* as **Publishing Content Types** and *Parent Content Type* as **Page**.

After that you just need to add this content type to the library where you want to add it. Page layout html can be anything you want to put as its content.

Comment: How can i add that content type to all my libraries and new ones? I have more than 200 libraries and once a week 1-3 new ones are created

Comment: You can create Powershell script for assigning that content types, but for that first you need to enable content type and with array you can go through loop to assign the same to any number of list or libraries.

Comment: For your reference you can check this list of operations for Powershell: http://pradiprathod.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/powershell-list-operations/